# DNS workaround for webhost DDoS

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, ddos

My webhoster seems to have some troubles with DDOS attacks and routing overload.
This makes my IP to be not available sometimes and I'd like to add a failover IP for the domain.

However, 2 A-Records means that it's similar to a load balancer which is NOT what i am looking for. I do not want the fallback machine to be accessed any time - except in case of real troubles or downtime of first choice IP.

Is there a out-of-the box solution that allows me such a failover ip?

If not, if it requires a DNS re-configuration: Is there a recommended script or similar that can be run on the secondary machine (of course, this is with a different hoster).
This has to check whether the first choice ip is down and must overwrite the A-record, right? This requires my domain hoster to provide an API for the DNS settings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any DNS provider that supports Dynamic DNS can assist with this requirement.

Let's assume you use [DynDns](http://www.dyndns.com/) and get a dynamic DNS name of `uptime.homeunix.com`<sup>Note 1</sup>.  Assume your DynDns username is foobarme, and your password is "LeTmeiN"

- Assume the address of your primary webhost is 192.0.2.100
- Assume the address of your backup webhost is 192.0.2.200
- Assume your web service's address is http://solid.rock.local/

Use [`ipcheck.py`](http://ipcheck.sourceforge.net/) to assign your primary address to `uptime.homeunix.com` (I'm using linux)...

```
$ python ipcheck.py -a 192.0.2.100 foobarme LeTmeiN uptime.homeunix.com
```

Now CNAME `solid.rock.local` to `uptime.homeunix.com`.

If you need to use the backup webhost, it's this easy...

```
$ python ipcheck.py -a 192.0.2.200 foobarme LeTmeiN uptime.homeunix.com
```

The DNS TTL on these [DynDns](http://www.dyndns.com/) DDNS records is typically one-minute... pretty low.

---

Note 1: BTW, `uptime.homeunix.com` is available right now if you like it :-)

Comment: thanks, can this script also do the reliable check for current ip being down for me? so it's only overwriting the DNS in case of issues with the prefered server.

Comment: This script will only assign ip addresses to the DDNS entry... the criteria for changing between your primary and backup webhost is outside it's capabilities